# Swift: How to convert a struct as dictionary along with hierarchical of keys

Tags: ios, swift, codable

I want to convert a **CollegeRequest** type to a dictionary or data to send it to a server while requesting POST-API.

Here is my **CollegeRequest** type:

```
struct CollegeRequest: Codable {
    struct Student: Codable {
        var id: Int
        var name: String
    }
    var student: Student
    var date: Date
}
```

Once converted (along with the **hierarchical keys**), it should be like this:

```
{
  "student.id": 3,
  "student.name": "Raj",
  "date": "2019-10-31T13:59:00+00:00"
}
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What's `Sendable`? Do you know about `Codable`?

Comment: "Please guide me" is not an actual question.

Comment: convert 'Struct' class..well..I'm sorry that this isn't related to the question, but I was triggered by that. Read the difference between class and struct, please!

Comment: • If you want JSON: 1) Adopt `Encodable` 2) Specify and *translate* all `CodingKeys` (e.g.`case id = "student.id"` 3) Implement `encode(to encoder` and encode everything *manually*. • If you want a dictionary write a custom method, that's more efficient than converting to JSON/PropertyList and then to dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Use [Encodable protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) to encode your cutom struct type CollegeRequest. Your structure needs a manual encoding

> If the structure of your Swift type differs from the structure of its
>   encoded form, you can provide a custom implementation of Encodable and
>   Decodable to define your own encoding and decoding logic. [source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

To encode the *CollegeRequest* to Data type, use [JSONEncoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder). An object that encodes instances of a data type as JSON objects.

Concerning the date stored property you you have to use *[JSONEncoder.DateEncodingStrategy.formatted(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder/dateencodingstrategy/formatted)*, the strategy that defers formatting settings to a supplied date formatter.

```
struct CollegeRequest: Codable {
    struct Student: Codable {
        var id: Int
        var name: String
    }
    var student: Student
    var date: Date

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case studentId = "student.id"
        case studentName = "student.name"
        case date
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {

        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(student.id, forKey: .studentId)
        try container.encode(student.name, forKey: .studentName)
        try container.encode(date, forKey: .date)
    }

    init(student: CollegeRequest.Student, date: Date) {
        self.student = student
        self.date = date
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let studentId = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .studentId)
        let studentName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .studentName)
        student = Student(id: studentId, name: studentName)
        date = try values.decode(Date.self, forKey: .date)
    }

}
```

---

**Usage**

```
let request = CollegeRequest(student: CollegeRequest.Student(id: 1, name: "John"), date: Date())
let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
let df = { let df = DateFormatter(); df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"; return df }() as DateFormatter
jsonEncoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .formatted(df)
let a: Data? = try? jsonEncoder.encode(request)
```

Comment: @RobNapier Answer Updated

Comment: My struct is Codable it's not Encodable.

Comment: It's throwing decodable error (Type 'CollegeRequest' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable')